# how to get the behavior of search input with the clear "x" button on regular text input?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the behavior of `<input type="search">` on regular `<input type="text">`.

I tried to use the `appearance: searchfield;` which didn't applied this special behavior.

How I want it to look:
[image]

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/a5b6b372dd0ceb2f0b5e09a822a52d21) (Tested on Chrome Browser, and it doesn't work)

Searching for a pure CSS/HTML solution

Comment: Something like this ? https://codepen.io/pheriannath/pen/pJWbjx

Comment: both aren't native, i want to get it only with css and HTML without adding new HTML elements or JS

Answer (score 5):

Demo: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/MWjdbgL

**Presented here three ways of solving the issue:**

1️⃣ When the `input` element has no *focus*, its `type` is set to `search`, which then shows the `x` (clear button), and when the element has *focus* - its type is set to `text`

```html
<input type="search" 
       onmouseup="this._timer=setTimeout(el=>{el.type='text'},0,this)" 
       onblur="clearTimeout(this._timer);this.type='search'" 
/>
```

2️⃣ Wrap the input with a `<form>` element so it could be cleared using native
 `<button type='clear'>`

```css
input{ padding:.5em; font:1em Arial;}
input[type='text']:placeholder-shown + button{ opacity:0; pointer-events:none;}

form{ display:inline-block; position: relative; }
form:hover input[type='text']:not(:placeholder-shown) + button{ opacity: 1 }
form button{
    --size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    line-height: var(--size);
    font-size: calc(var(--size) - 3px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: calc(var(--size)/2);
    margin: auto;
    background-color: salmon;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text'  placeholder=' ' />
  <button type='reset'>&times;</button>
</form>
```

3️⃣ Use a *non-`<form>`* wrapper and javascript

```css
input{ padding:.5em; font:1em Arial; }
input[type='text']:placeholder-shown + button{ opacity:0; pointer-events:none;}

.inputWrap{ display:inline-block; position: relative; }
.inputWrap:hover input[type='text']:not(:placeholder-shown) + button{ opacity: 1 }
.inputWrap button{
    --size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    line-height: var(--size);
    font-size: calc(var(--size) - 3px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: calc(var(--size)/2);
    margin: auto;
    background-color: salmon;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='inputWrap'>
  <input type='text'  placeholder=' ' />
  <button type='reset' onclick='this.previousElementSibling.value=""'>&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I preferred something without adding any new HTML element, but maybe there isn't any other choice.

Let's wait, if someone can solve it without adding new HTML element, if not I will take this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .border-0{
                border: none;
            }
            .search-border{
                border: 1px solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 200px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>      
         <div class="search-border">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="border-0">
            <img src="/assets/close-icon-light.svg">      
         </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi,
Please try this code if this satisfies you. Use width of your choice for the search box. Also use a suitable close icon.